# How to plot specific columns from xlsx file

Tags: python

I need to plot the 'value' and 'channel' columns versus each other from SHEET 4 of the excel file. The columns have over 1000 numbers in it. How would I do this with python?

[Excel file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrPO3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas to first import the sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('EXCELNAME','SHEET4')
df.plot('Value','Channel')
```

Then you can plot it using pandas' plotting tools.